# Setting up Kafka in Spring Boot without using the starter

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'd like to configure Spring Boot application with Kafka support without actually using the Spring's Kafka starters.

I would like to use the `org.apache` library, but I'm still trying to figure out the best way in order to do that.

There would be a topic, producer & 2 consumers. Whenever a message is posted onto the topic, I'd like the consumers to consume it.

I can programmatically configure the Kafka consumers, create a scheduler that would check the topic for the presence of messages, like every half a second or so.

Then, the event would be posted and the Spring Boot's Event Listener would capture it and delegate further - where the logic would happen.

That would certainly work, but I'm sure there are other workarounds.